# The Witches : A Discworld Adventure - Two problems a turn?

Tags: discworld-the-witches

I'm a little confused over the movement and secondary action rules in The Witches.

The rules say

> Move Witch - you may perform this action twice. After you have finished moving your witch you must perform one secondary action which will be dictated by where you have moved.

Does this mean I can perform two secondary actions, one with each 'Move witch' on only one secondary action after my two 'Move Witch' movements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of digging in BGG turned up this [thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1038862/movement-originally-misunderstood-several-gamers) which dates back to the prototype period and includes a response from the designer.

> Hi Pasquale,
> Glad you like our games. As to your question, the second is correct (place
> trouble, move one/two spaces, secondary action, move one/two spaces,
> secondary action).
> Best
> Martin

So the correct way to play is to allow two movements (up to two spaces or via broomstick) and two secondary actions within a single player turn.

Total turn order looks like;

Add Problem > Move > Secondary Action > Move > Secondary Action > Refill Hand